# is it possible to code custom ahah effects?

Tags: 6, javascript, ajax

I'm just getting into D6's FAPI ahah property and I was wondering - in addition to the "stock" effects, is it possible to use jQuery to create custom effects?
I'm trying to get a horizontal slide.

Thanks!

Stephanie

Comment: In the form api docs, it says something along the lines of `#ahah['effect']

Description: Specifies the effect used when adding the content from an AHAH request.

Values: String. Possible values: 'none' (default), 'fade', 'slide'. If the interface elements library is installed, any effect with the name effectToggle may also be used.` Unfortunately, the 'interface elements library' link mentioned goes to a dead one, but I am going to assume they are talking about the jquery ui library/module so I'd look into trying it that way.